# linux capabilities to read environment variables?

Tags: environment-variables, services, capabilities

I'd like to run a service as a non-privileged user, but it needs to bind to a system port number (i.e. less than 1024), so I give it `setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' <path for service>`, all good.

Problem is, on startup, the service reads environment vars and for some reason it can't do that when it has `cap_net_bind_service`. So, with two copies of the executable, one with `cap_net_bind_service`, one without, only the one without can read environment vars.

It's as though there's a default set of capabilities that allows reading env vars, but the exe loses that capability when I give it `cap_net_bind_service`. Is that right, or is something else going on? What additional capability might I need to give to the service so that it can read env vars? There's nothing in [capability.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/capability.h) that jumps out as being "allow env var reading"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got to the bottom of it. In brief, the binary is using [`secure_getenv`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/secure_getenv.3.html) to access environment variables. This returns `null`, instead of accessing the variables, when the binary is run in "secure execution" mode (`AT_SECURE=1`). Having any capability set, causes it to run in this mode.

Confirm that the binary is using `secure_getenv` using `readelf`:

```
readelf -a <path for service> | grep getenv
00000040ac28  004b00000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000 secure_getenv@GLIBC_2.17 + 0
00000040ad90  007a00000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000 getenv@GLIBC_2.2.5 + 0
    75: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND secure_getenv@GLIBC_2.17 (6)
   122: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND getenv@GLIBC_2.2.5 (2)
```

Confirm that it's running in secure execution mode with environment variables (how ironic!) `LD_DEBUG=all` and/or `LD_SHOW_AUXV` (see [`man ld.so`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html)).

If it isn't then `LD_SHOW_AUXV` produces output with `AT_SECURE` set to 0. There is no output from `LD_SHOW_AUXV` when it is running in secure execution mode.

Normally, there is/isn't output from `LD_DEBUG` too when it is/isn't running in secure execution mode. However, if `/etc/suid-debug` is present (empty file, create with touch), then `LD_DEBUG` will produce output when running in secure execution mode.

See [`man getauxval`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getauxval.3.html) for more information about `AT_SECURE` and secure execution mode.